# Access / Alter user registration form submit button in $form variable

Tags: 8, forms, users

In drupal 8, I have created a custom module to alter the user login and register forms in 2 class that extends `UserLoginForm` and `RegisterForm` respectively.

Whereas for the login form I can add some link in the `$form['action']` array or add a class to the submit button:

```
 $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes'] = [
    'class' => ['btn', 'btn-primary'],
 ];
```

a contrario, there is no *action* array in user register `$form` variable(!)

So how can I access in my class the submit button, and more generally, the *action* array?

Comment: In general if you do hook_form_FORM_ID_alter like "YOURMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)" you can access $form['actions']['submit'] where you can provide #attributes to it.

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to access it in the extended Class, but I will go for it if I cannot find the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `UserLoginForm` is a regular form based on form api, `RegisterForm` is an entity form, where the actions are defined in a separate method [EntityForm::actions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityForm.php/function/EntityForm%3A%3Aactions/8.4.x), which is overridden in `RegisterForm`:

```
  protected function actions(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element = parent::actions($form, $form_state);
    $element['submit']['#value'] = $this->t('Create new account');
    return $element;
  }
```

which you can override again in your extended class.

Comment: Thanks, I just found it when I saw your comment :-). But now my class just throw an error so... I must have miss something on class extends...